# In NLP, tokens not seen in training sample, but you know or don't know what they are

Tags: natural-language-processing

In NLP, do you distinguish tokens that you don't observe in a training sample and still expect that they may occur in a test sample, between

- those you know what they are, and
- those you don't know what they are, and how many of them

If yes, how do you treat them differently to estimate the probabilities in N-grams?

Comment: Have you heard of Laplacian smoothing and Bayesian smoothing?  If not, do some research on them...

Comment: yes. I know them. But for those words you don't see in the training sample, and don't know who they are, and how many of them, I don't know how to apply Laplace smoothing and Bayesian smoothing. The methods seem only apply to the case that you know what they are and how many of them.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to edit your question to explain what techniques you have already considered and why they don't seem to apply to your situation?

Comment: I don't have techiques to solve the second case.

Comment: Again, rather than adding comments here, I recommend that you edit the question.  On this site, we expect the question to stand alone; people should not have to read the comments to get everything.  Comments exist solely to help you improve the question.  We also expect that you'll tell us what you tried, and if you know of some seemingly-relevant approach that doesn't actually solve your problem, we'd normally expect you to mention it in the question and explain why it doesn't actually solve your problem.  So, please click the "edit" button underneath your question and improve it.